# Toeplitz matrix using numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, toeplitz

In Octave or Matlab there is a neat, compact way to create large Toeplitz matrices, for example:

```
T = toeplitz([1,-0.25,zeros(1,20)])
```

That saves a lot of time that would otherwise be spent to fill the matrix with dozens or hundreds of zeros by using extra lines of code.

Yet I don't seem to be able to do the same with neither scipy or numpy, although those two libraries have both toeplitz() and zeros() functions.
Is there a similar way to do that or do I have to put together a routine of my own to do that (not a huge problem, but still a nuisance)?

Thanks,

F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently I think the best you can do is:

```
from numpy import concatenate, zeros
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

toeplitz(concatenate([[1., -.25], zeros(20)]))
```

As of python 3.5 however we'll have:

```
toeplitz([1., -.25, *zeros(20)])
```

So that's something to look forward to.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that worked perfectly!

I forgot to mention though that I don't use Python 3.x yet.  I also made a mistake: as far as I know, numpy does not have toeplitz().  That one is part of scipy.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using [r_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

toeplitz(np.r_[1, -0.25, np.zeros(20)])
```

You can also work with lists:

```py
toeplitz([1, -0.25] + [0]*20)
```